# CakePHP Get IP give me a wrong address

Tags: cakephp, ip

I use CakePHP 2.x and :

```
echo $this->request->clientIp();
```

return me

> ::1

My ask is: Where is mistake bacause ::1 is no my IP :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`::1` is local host in `IPv6`

Read more here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost